# OpenGL works with prebuilt Qt but not when compiled by myself

Tags: qt, opengl

I have problems with OpenGL not working on self-compiled Qt 5.9.6 on windows 10. The OpenGL Examples bundled with Qt does not work but shows only a grey screen. No error message or crash. This is the situation when I link the example OpenGL apps (e.g. the Cube app) with the Qt libraries that I compiled myself.

When I link them with the prebuilt Qt distribution package they work as expected. So there must be something wrong with the Qt compilation. I have used the following configuration to compile Qt:

```
configure 
-opensource 
-debug 
-mp 
-nomake examples (I compiled the examples later manually)
-nomake tests 
-skip androidextras 
-skip gamepad
-skip macextras
-skip purchasing
-skip speech
-skip serialbus
-skip serialport
-opengl desktop
```

And I am compiling with the Visual Studio 2013 for x86_64 platform.

Originally, I faced the problem when using a middleware software which utilizes the Qt OpenGL libraries. It gave the error code 1282 (GL_INVALID_OPERATION) when trying to do practically anything OpenGL related. That middleware also works when linked against the prebuilt Qt.

I am using a NVidia GeForce 1080 GTX GPU (latest drivers at this time), if that matters.

Any insight on what could be the problem?